# Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser changes ± Ascii 241 to ? Ascii 63

Tags: .net, vb.net, ascii

I am using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Fileio.TextFieldParser to parse a CSV file that was created with Excel 2003.  The parser is working great with the exception that it is converting extended ascii values to question marks!  So if the file content was:

> ± 3
>   The TextFieldParser is returning
>   ? 3

I have tried all of the encodings in the System.Text.Encoding package with no luck.  I thought I had it with UTF7 but it was dropping other characters like replacing the + sign with  a space.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'ASCII 241'. The meaning of bytes 128-255 is defined by **extensions to** ASCII, and there are a heck of a lot of these.

Comment: Have you checked what the file is saved as?  Open it in Notepad and select Save As, there should be a dropdown that you can select the encoding from.  Check what it is there, I suspect ANSI. You might want to try and save it as UTF-8 and then run it through your app again.

Answer (score 18):

The Microsoft.VisualBasic.Fileio.TextFieldParser defaults to UTF8 encoding, but the text file is in the system's current ANSI encoding.  Use one of the constructors that take an encoding like: [TextFieldParser(string path, Encoding defaultEncoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128086.aspx).

You can pass in [System.Text.Encoding.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx) for your encoding or construct a new Encoding Object passing in a code page.  The default on English Windows is [1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim s As String = "± 3"
    'this produces the ?
    Dim b() As Byte = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)

    'try this
    Dim anEncoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)
    b = anEncoding.GetBytes(s)

    s = anEncoding.GetChars(b) 'check to see if it round-trips
```